# Pronormal subgroups of direct products

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G = A \times B$. Let $U = A \times \pi_B(U) \leq G$ such that $\pi_B(U)$ is pronormal in $B$. Then $U$ is pronormal in $G$.

This is part of a proof of Proposition 4.3 in [Pronormal subgroup of a direct product of groups](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S002186930800611X/1-s2.0-S002186930800611X-main.pdf?_tid=b03acdc0-5251-11e6-8bdd-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1469442328_c6ce88294c49f6b9d337f94cd07806b2)

The author says that ''easily $U$ is pronormal in $G$'

Here's my attempt so far: Let $(a, b) \in G$. Since $\pi_B(U)$ is pronormal $B$, there exists $b' \in \langle \pi_B(U), b\pi_B(U)b^{-1} \rangle$ such that $b'\pi_B(U)b'^{-1} = b\pi_B(U)b^{-1}$  for all $b\in B$.

Now $(a, b') \in \langle A \times \pi_B(U), (a, b)( A \times \pi_B(U))(a^{-1}, b^{-1}) \rangle$. If I can show that $(a, b')(A \times \pi_B(U))(a^{-1}, b'^{-1}) = (a, b)( A \times \pi_B(U))(a^{-1}, b^{-1})$, then I will be done.

$$ \begin{align} 
(a, b')(A \times \pi_B(U))(a^{-1}, b'^{-1}) &= (1, b')A(1, b'^{-1}) \times (a, 1)(1, b')(\pi_B(U))(1, b'^{-1})(a^{-1}, 1) \\ &= (1, b')A(1, b'^{-1}) \times (a, 1)(1, b)(\pi_B(U))(1, b^{-1})(a^{-1}, 1) \\&= (1, b')A(1, b'^{-1}) \times (a, b)(\pi_B(U))(a^{-1}, b^{-1}) \end{align} $$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: So given conjugation by some $(a,b)$, does the "obvious" choice of $(a,b')$ where $b'$ is from the pronormality of $\pi_B(U)$ not work?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as my internet connection was down. I have added your proposed method to the question. please have a look at it as I have still run into problems

Comment: You just need to use that $A$ and $\pi_B(U)$ centralize each other.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thank you for your help. I have managed to show the equality needed but from above we have $b' \in \langle \pi_B(U), b\pi_B(U)b^{-1} \rangle$, how does that guarantee $(a, b') \in \langle A\times \pi_b(U), (a,b)(A \times \pi_b(U))(a^{-1}, b^{-1}) \rangle$ as we have assumed?